# How to show images to the extreme end of the UISlider?

Tags: iphone

I'm implementing UISlider. I want to show images to the extreme end of the slider(eg. volume control images of mute and full sound). I'm using

UIImage *maximumValueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speaker_plus.png"];

UIImage *minimumValueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speaker_minus.png"];

slider.maximumValueImage = maximumValueImage;

slider.minimumValueImage = minimumValueImage;

How to implement the following method?

-(CGRect)maximumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
-(CGRect)minimumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did same for one of my app. Below is code.

```
UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"leftslide.png"]
                            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightslide.png"]
                                stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgSlider.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this Help.

These are the images I used.

1. Black image is leftside.png
2. White image is rightside.png
3. Black Circle is imgSlider.png

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Why you want to implement this method ?